# R regex search to capture URLs

Tags: regex, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R regular expression: http matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413294/r-regular-expression-http-matching)

I'm working to capture URLs from a chunk of source code using regex.

The URL's follow a pattern and are in the following form:

- www.google.com/..../1-1,1"
- www.google.com/..../1-2,2"
- www.google.com/..../1-20,20"

so far I can get to the url using the following code:

```
pattern = paste("1-", 1:20,",", 1:20, "\"", sep="")
```

this gives me a vector of:

- 1-1,1
- 1-2,2
- .....
- 1-20,20

then I can use these vectors to give me a position or the URLs inside the soure code .

Let's say for example that the whole source code is simply: "http://www.google.com/word/1-1,1>"

```
`regexpr("1-1,1", test1k, TRUE)`
```

gives me:

> [1] 28 attr(,"match.length") [1] 5

this means that the pattern 1-1,1 starts at length 28. Given this information, how would I select the whole URL starting at "http://ww..." until the end "1-1,1>".

I guess what I'm asking is, give the position 28, is there a function to select the nearest "http://" string going backwards (this marks the start of the URL). Similarly, given the position 28, is there a way to select the nearest ">" character going forward (this marks the end of the URL).

Comment: You should be more specific about what you're trying to do: note that you include http and > in your definition of the URL you're trying to capture, but do not include them in your list at the start of the question (instead, you include an ending quotation mark). However, I think my answer below covers what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than creating all possible combinations, just use the `\\d` character, which will match any digit. For example:

```
 regexpr("1-\\d+,\\d+", test1k, TRUE)
```

To select the whole URL, you want to start the regular expression with "http", and then have it continue until the first time this pattern is matched. One simple way is:

```
regexpr("http.*?1-\\d+,\\d+", test1k, TRUE)
```

The `.*` pattern has three parts. The `.` matches any character, the `*` means "any number of that character, and the `?` means that it's not greedy (otherwise, this will take up the entire string from the first http to the last `1-\\d+,\\d+`.

For example:

```
> regexpr("http.*1-?\\d+,\\d+", "The URL that you are looking for is http://www.google.com/word/1-1,1", TRUE)
[1] 37
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 32
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I got it working, thanks a lot! btw do you know of a longer explanation to ? that makes it non-greedy? That part still confuses me

Comment: You should read an in-depth guide to regular expressions (books have been written on the subject). A good start is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).